Sort by `rowid` with Room a DTO with a String primary key
I have a DTO class that has a String primary key e.g.:
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "guid") val guid: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
...
)

Now I need to sort the items by their insertion order i.e. by the hidden rowid column. If my primary key is an integer type with @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true), it is an alias for the hidden rowid, so I can sort by my "id". But in the case of non-integer primary keys, I am not able to sort by the hidden rowid (to get insertion order of filtered items).
When I add ORDER BY rowid DESC into my @Query(...), Android studio recognizes that the rowid exists and does not complain. But the Room KSP compiler complains with error:
There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: rowid)

I am doing something wrong or is this a bug/feature in Room's KSP compiler? How can I sort by the hidden rowid column with Room? I really don't want to add a dummy indexed column just for that.


I am doing something wrong or is this a bug/feature in Room's KSP compiler?

A bug with KSP may well be the case, you do not appear to be doing anything wrong, as the demo below, using kapt shows.

How can I sort by the hidden rowid column with Room?

Option 1
Use the @SkipQueryVerification annotation on the respective function(s) in the interface/abstract class(es).

This could result in run time exceptions if it is masking incorrect SQL.

Option 2
As per the note above you could use KAPT rather than KSP.
Option 3
Do not worry about I really don't want to add a dummy indexed column just for that.
That is unless the table is a WITHOUT ROWID table, which Room doesn't support, then the hidden rowid column and the index WILL EXIST.
So perhaps you could consider:-
@Entity(indices = [Index("guid", unique = true)])
data class ItemV2(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "insertorder") val insertorder: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name="guid") val guid: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="title") val title: String
)

Where the insertorder column is an alias of the rowid column, so you can use insertorder (or whatever name you fell is appropriate). Instead of being the primary key, the guid column is a unique index.

Column and index wise there is little difference as the rowid column and the index thereon exist.

Note the lack autoGenerate=true. it is NOT autoGenerate=true that makes the column an alias of the rowid. What actually makes  a column an alias of the rowid is that the column is the PRIMARY KEY and that the column is defined with a type that is exactly INTEGER.

Room will use the column type INTEGER for integer type fields (e.g. Long, Int, Byte ....).

SQLite has a flexible approach to column types, so INT, BIGINT and even something like ABCDEFGHINT all have a type affinity of INTEGER BUT they would not result in aliasing the rowid. However, Room only uses the types INTEGER, REAL, TEXT or BLOB for the column type.




Using autoGenerate=true does introduce unecessary/wasteful components. That is it results in the use of the SQLite AUTOINCREMENT, which for the nuance that generated values must be greater requires the existence and use of the sqlite_sequence table to keep a record of the highest ever rowid value.

as per https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html which has, as the very first, statement:- The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.


Due to how Room handles non-autoGenerate=true integer primary keys, instead of 0 a value of null equates to the value being generated hence the use of Long?=null (0 would result in a value of 0 being used).


Option 4 (not tested)
You could use an @RawQuery, where the SQL is not checked at compile time.

again like option 1 incorrect SQL would result in a run time error.


Demo
The following code demonstrates Options 1 and 2:--
The @Entity annotated classes (original and suggested for option 2):-
@Entity
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "guid") val guid: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String
)

@Entity(indices = [Index("guid", unique = true)])
data class ItemV2(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "insertorder") val insertorder: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name="guid") val guid: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="title") val title: String
)

The @Dao annotated interface and the functions therein:-
@Dao
interface AllDAOS {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(item: Item): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(itemV2: ItemV2): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY rowid")
    fun getItemsByinsertorder(): List<Item>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM itemV2 ORDER BY insertorder")
    fun getItemV2sByinsertorder(): List<ItemV2>
}

Some activity code to demonstrate:-
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getAllDAOs()

    dao.insert(Item("X","xxxx"))
    dao.insert(Item("A","aaaa"))
    dao.insert(Item("M","mmmm"))
    dao.insert(ItemV2(guid ="X",title = "xxxx"))
    dao.insert(ItemV2(guid ="A",title = "aaaa"))
    dao.insert(ItemV2(guid ="M",title = "mmmm"))

    for (item in dao.getItemsByinsertorder()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO_ITEM","GUID is ${item.guid} Title is ${item.title}")
    }
    for (itemv2 in dao.getItemV2sByinsertorder()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO_ITEM","GUID is ${itemv2.guid} Title is ${itemv2.title} InsertionOrder is ${itemv2.insertorder}")
    }

Result output to the Log:-
D/DBINFO_ITEM: GUID is X Title is xxxx
D/DBINFO_ITEM: GUID is A Title is aaaa
D/DBINFO_ITEM: GUID is M Title is mmmm
D/DBINFO_ITEM: GUID is X Title is xxxx InsertionOrder is 1
D/DBINFO_ITEM: GUID is A Title is aaaa InsertionOrder is 2
D/DBINFO_ITEM: GUID is M Title is mmmm InsertionOrder is 3


The Item table, ordered by the rowid, demonstrates that it it good to use via KAPT (i.e. the first 3 output lines)

Results via App Inspection (i.e. the actual database)


And more importantly re the "no real difference" aspect:-


As can be seen the primary key is not listed as a separate component, but because the rowid has been used for the Item table then an index has been automatically assigned as sqlite_autoindex_Item_1.


Thanks for the thorough answer, you directed me into the right direction! I tried @SkipQueryVerification, which looks like what I really want and it crashed in runtime with SQLiteException: no such column: rowid (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR). Than it clicked. I have a JOIN in my query so just rowid is ambiguous. After specifying also the table name e.g. my_table.rowid it works! Also without @SkipQueryVerification and the KSP is now happy, no errors. It was just my mistake and a bad error message.

@shelll good that  you found the issue.

The rowid column only exists when you have an integer primary key in your table. In this case, rowid is an alias for that primary key. However, if your primary key is not an integer, the rowid is not visible. That's why you can only use rowid in your query if your table has an integer primary key.
The official SQLite documentation explains this:

If the rowid is not aliased by INTEGER PRIMARY KEY then it is not
persistent and might change. In particular the VACUUM command will
change rowids for tables that do not declare an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
Therefore, applications should not normally access the rowid directly,
but instead use an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

In your case, since you're using a string primary key, sqlite doesn't create a rowid, and that's why you can't sort by it.

That is not what the documantion says. Even the quoted paragraph says "it is not persistent and might change" i.e. it exists. The only cases where SQLite does not create rowid, per the linked specification, are in virtual tables and tables that are created with WITHOUT ROWID. All other tables have it. And the Room library doesn't create tables with WITHOUT ROWID.
